# How to make labels in AGOL look exactly the same as they do in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: python, arcgis, fme

I recently prepared a very good looking map with labels in ArcGIS Pro (v3.2.1) and published it in AGOL. Now in AGOL labels are not looking the same way as they do in ArcGIS Pro! I tried to convert them into annotations or graphics but until now without success.

How can I export my map in ArcGIS Pro as WebMap without loosing label placing settings?

Link below desctibes exactly my issue but it my case it didn't work!

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/arcgis-pro-labels-not-displaying-properly-in/td-p/1290243

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [gis.se]?